# Problems with random # generators in c# (EDITED)

Tags: c#, class, oop, c#-4.0, object

## EDITED

I have this in the Main, where I set up the objects and call the Player class. Sorry for the lack of comments in the code.

```
        Player MyPlayer;
    MyPlayer = new Player();
    Hiders[] MyHiders = new Hiders[4];



    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        MyHiders[i] = new Hiders();
    }

    while (FoundAll == false)
    {
        MyPlayer.Move();
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            MyHiders[i].DisplayDistance(MyPlayer.x, MyPlayer.y);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            MyHiders[i].CheckCapture(MyPlayer.x, MyPlayer.y);
        }

        FoundAll = true;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (MyHiders[i].Found == false)
            {
                FoundAll = false;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
```

And these classes

```
    class Player
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public void Move()
    {
        string buffer;
        Console.WriteLine("Where would you like to move?");
        buffer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (buffer == "u")
        {
            x++;
        }
        if (buffer == "d")
        {
            x--;
        }
        if (buffer == "l")
        {
            y--;
        }
        if (buffer == "r")
        {
            y++;
        }
    }
}
class Hiders
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public bool Found;
    int[,] map = new int[10, 10];
    Random MyRandom = new Random();
    int Randomhx;
    int Randomhy;

    public Hiders(int hx, int hy)
    {
        MyRandom = new Random();
        Randomhx = MyRandom.Next(1, 10);
        Randomhy = MyRandom.Next(1, 10);
    }

    public Hiders()
    {

    }

    public void DisplayDistance(int px, int py)
    {
        double distance;

        distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x - px, 2) + Math.Pow(y - py, 2));

        Console.WriteLine(distance);
    }

    public void CheckCapture(int px, int py)
    {
        if (Randomhx == px & Randomhy == py)
        {

            Found = true;


        }
    }
}
```

All of the hiders are getting the same value. How do I make it so that they change from 1-10. This should be working.

Comment: Do you mean DisplayDistance method of Hiders class? If this is the case, you already call it with MyHiders[i].DisplayDistance(MyPlayer.x, MyPlayer.y);

Comment: Okay, now I see. There was some misplaced things that made it so that it says to go up/down left/right before it displays distances

Comment: I edited it, and changed the question. All of the hiders are coming up the same value. How do i change their position on the grid?

Comment: Even if you manage to make the random working, you will still get zero for x & y (in Hiders class) because you never initialize them.

Comment: How do I initialize them mbm?

Answer (score 3):

Each instance of Hiders is instantiating its own instance of Random. Since they are all being instantiated nearly simultaneously, and Random uses the system clock as the default seed, all the instances of Random will produce the same value sequence. My recommendation is to have the instances of Hiders to share a single instance of Random.

Comment: Use a static field in the `Hiders` class rather than the current instance field and remove the unnecessary `new Random()` in the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

default constructor for random uses the system time as a seed.  Try using random with a seed such as Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()

```
var rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
```

Comment: I have no idea what that is. How would I set that up?

Comment: Do I replace that with `MyRandom = new Random();`?

Comment: Yes - replace all uses of the default constructor with the one with the seed overload.

Comment: That doesn't work. I think that I need to somehow set `private int x` and `private int y` at the beginning of `class Hiders` to `Randomhx` and `Randomhy`. How do I do that though? i've tried for hours.

Comment: `public Hiders(int hx, int hy)
    {
        var MyRandom = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        x = Randomhx = MyRandom.Next(1, 10);
        y = Randomhy = MyRandom.Next(1, 10);
    }`

Answer (score -1):

As per @DeveloperGuo answer you should use different seed so that you will get different random value. This change should work.

```
public Hiders()
{
   MyRandom = new Random( Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode() );
   x = MyRandom.Next( 1, 10 );
   y = MyRandom.Next( 1, 10 );
}
```

EDIT:

Since my example above is not actually a good practice here is another shot:

```
  public Start_New_Game()
  {
     bool FoundAll = false;
     int i;
     Player MyPlayer;
     MyPlayer = new Player();
     Hiders[] MyHiders = new Hiders[ 4 ];
     HiderGenerator hiderGenerator = new HiderGenerator();

     for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
     {
        MyHiders[ i ] = hiderGenerator.Get_New_Hider();
     }

     while ( FoundAll == false )
     {
        MyPlayer.Move();
        for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
        {
           MyHiders[ i ].DisplayDistance( MyPlayer.x, MyPlayer.y );
        }
        for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
        {
           MyHiders[ i ].CheckCapture( MyPlayer.x, MyPlayer.y );
        }

        FoundAll = true;
        for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
        {
           if ( MyHiders[ i ].Found == false )
           {
              FoundAll = false;
           }
        }
     }
     Console.WriteLine( "You Win!" );
  }

  class Player
  {
     public int x;
     public int y;

     public void Move()
     {
        string buffer;
        Console.WriteLine( "Where would you like to move?" );
        buffer = Console.ReadLine();
        if ( buffer == "u" )
        {
           x++;
        }
        if ( buffer == "d" )
        {
           x--;
        }
        if ( buffer == "l" )
        {
           y--;
        }
        if ( buffer == "r" )
        {
           y++;
        }
     }
  }

  class HiderGenerator
  { 
     Random MyRandom = new Random();
     public Hiders Get_New_Hider()
     {
        return new Hiders( MyRandom.Next(1,10), MyRandom.Next(1,10) );
     }
  }

  class Hiders
  {
     private int x;
     private int y;

     public bool Found;
     int[,] map = new int[ 10, 10 ];

     public Hiders( int x, int y )
     {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
     }

     public void DisplayDistance( int px, int py )
     {
        if ( Found )
           return;

        double distance;

        distance = Math.Sqrt( Math.Pow( x - px, 2 ) + Math.Pow( y - py, 2 ) );

        Console.WriteLine( distance );
     }

     public void CheckCapture( int px, int py )
     {
        if ( Found )
           return;

        if ( x == px && y == py )
        {
           Found = true;
        }
     }
  }
```

This is not the a perfect answer but at least it could be a starting point.

Comment: That works, but now when I get onto a hider (distance = 0), it does not take it out of the displaydistance and it does not count it as found

Comment: @user3158491 because you are comparing with Randomx & Randomy instead of x & y in the CheckCapture method

Comment: In the CheckCapture, I changed Randomhx and Randomhy to x and y, but it does the same thing.